# Error: "Call to member function on a non-object..." in Magento

Tags: php, magento

When I place the following code at the bottom of my new_grid.phtml template file, it works fine, without any any errors. But when it is placed at the top of the file, I get a fatal error: "Call to member function getRelatedLinkCollection() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\MYSITE\magento\app\design\frontend\MYSITE\default\template\catalog\product\widget\new\content\new_grid.phtml on line 32.

```
<?php
  foreach ($_product->getRelatedLinkCollection() as $link) {
  $dats= $link->getLinkedProductId();
  }
?>
```

I would like to get this code working specifically at the top of the file, because I'd like to output generated HTML in a particular structure. Any idea why I'm getting this error and what I can do to correct it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the contents of your `new_grid.phtml` file?

Otherwise, make sure the foreach loop is immediately after the line which contains `$_product =`